# Volley cancel request

Tags: android, android-volley

i am fetching data from volley my problem is some time when user press back button request continues and app crash as activity is finish and then response is coming so i am calling on back press

```
RequestQueue.cancelAll(requesttag)
 i am seting tag as 
 AppRequest.settag(requesttag)
```

but its good to call cancel every time user press back button ? i haven't found what where i can check if that request is in progress then only cancel . any good way to avoid it

Comment: I don't think you need to check. Volley will handle it itself. If there's a request with that TAG, volley will cancel it else nothing will happen. Alternatively you could set a boolean to true when request is made and if back button is pressed just check the values of this boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using tag to cancel all request. you can use filter,

```
mRequestQueue.cancelAll(new RequestQueue.RequestFilter() {
@Override
    public boolean apply(Request<?> request) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: You can cancel all request from RequestQueue by this code.

Comment: when this will execute ?

Comment: You can use it in back button press event handler

Comment: RequestQueue.cancelAll do same think na if you see inner code for cancel all   public void cancelAll(final Object tag) {
        if (tag == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot cancelAll with a null tag");
        }
        cancelAll(new RequestFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Request<?> request) {
                return request.getTag() == tag;
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Yes but in that case RequestFilter will always return `true`, please try once

Answer (score 1):

duplicate question
you should stop volley in your onPause and onStop. 
[Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774667/cancel-all-volley-requests-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AsynTask for fetching data from the server, then you can define an instance of that Asynctask. And when user presses back button you can cancel that task specifically like this

```
 FetchDataListTask fetchDataListAsyncTask;
 fetchDataListAsyncTask = new FetchDataListTask(true);
 fetchDataListAsyncTask.execute();
```

And put this in your Onbackpressed() method

```
if (fetchLeadListAsyncTask != null) {
                fetchLeadListAsyncTask.cancel(true);
            }
```

Comment: using volley not async

Comment: have you tried cancelling all request in onPause()  method