# Is it possible to stop asynctask from another activity or fragment?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to close or kill asynctask which is running in background. I am using a navigation bar. Using asynctask.cancel is not working .I am passing asynctask object  through main activity to navigation drawer adapter. but its not working.  My question is how to stop asynctask from another activity? or how to kill asynctask anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try using task.cancel(true);

The documentation of AsyncTask provides some additional details in the 'Cancelling a task' section:

A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

In your First_Activity define the task as: **static AsyncTask loadt;**

and where necessary call it **loadt = new LoadViewTask().execute();**

In your Second_Activity you can call **First_Activity.loadt.cancel(true);**

You will receive the control @ **onCancelled()** function of **LoadViewTask**

Comment: tnx but my question is can i stop  from another activity

Comment: yes. use the same function above (task.cancel(true)).

Comment: but how to get object reference i m passing troughs naviation draver adapter but not working

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RequestQueue`, and manage queue in your `Application` file. You can follow this links;

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

[Cancel All Volley Requests Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774667/cancel-all-volley-requests-android)